# How to convert a string of characters to its 8-bit ASCII form in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert a string of characters to its 8-bit binary form. Each character's binary value should be concatenated with the rest and I want to remove the "0b" at the beginning as well. How can I do this with Python?

Comment: ASCII is 7 bit.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to convert a string of ASCII characters to a string concatenation of their binary digits? E.g: `"abc" -> "011000010110001001100011"`?

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the code you are trying with to make your question more clear ?

Comment: I meant I wanted to convert it to 8-bit binary form. Yes, "abc" would be 011000010110001001100011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's builtin function `bin` takes an integer and converts it to a number prefixed with "0b".

Python's other builtin method, `ord`, returns an integer representing a Unicode code point for a given character. Since Unicode is a superset of ascii, `ord` will return the ASCII value for any ASCII character.

You can use `join` to concatenate an iterable of the binary values for each character, and then get rid of the `b`s

```
>>> def string2bin(string):
...     return ''.join(bin(ord(c)) for c in string).replace('b','')
... 
>>> string2bin('abc') == "011000010110001001100011"
True
```